# Treasure Goblin rifts probability

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm wondering what is the real probability to open a Treasure Goblin rift? Because I have made it one time and I have killed at least 200 Treasure Goblins. I did some research but I've found nothing. Does someone know the probability? Thanks!

Comment: I have not found anything, too. From personal experience and from some people's video guides it seems around 1-2%, unlikely 3%. You case of 1 per 200 seems like an unlucky streak to me. Also, remember that goblins in Rifts can't open a portal, so exclude those from your count.

Comment: I'm voting to close as off topic since the real calculation is known only from developper and any answer even based on experience would just be an educated guess. Now from my experience I'd say about 5% chance. I've goten in the chamber about 10+ times since it was introduced and I've killed in adventure mdoe about 200+ gobelin. 1 or 2% seems way too low. Also be aware that the goblin rift don't spawn in Nephalem rifts

Comment: Maybe some stats are taken into consideration when rolling for the portal. I've killed >300 treasure goblins. Not once have I seen this portal... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability is **unknown**. Some things to take into consideration:

- Spawns from random Treasure Goblins at level 70 in Adventure mode
- Only players present when the rift spawned can enter it
- Cannot spawn in rifts

You can kill a million of them in a rift and you'll never see the portal.

Comment: Ah, that will be why I've never seen one then. Thanks for that info

Comment: @Panomosh You're most welcome my good man!